# Cauchy Mean Value Theorem Proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

> Prove the following version of the Mean Value Theorem using Rolle’s theorem: Suppose $f, g$ are two functions defined on $[a,b$] that are

1. continuous on $[a, b]$,
2. differentiable on $(a, b)$,
3. $g'(x)$ is never 0 on $[a,b]$,
4. $g(a) \ne g(b)$.

> Then for some $c \in (a, b)$
>   $$\frac{f′(c)}{g′(c)}=\frac{f(b) − f(a)}{g(b) − g(a)}$$
>   Consider the function $h(x) = f (x)[g(a) − g(b)] − g(x)[f (a) − f (b)].$

How do you come up with the equation for the function $h(x) = f (x)[g(a) − g(b)] − g(x)[f (a) − f (b)]$?

Answer (score 3):

If you cross multiply $$\frac{f′(c)}{g′(c)}=\frac{f(b) − f(a)}{g(b) − g(a)}$$

you come up with the expression $$f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]-g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)]=0$$

which is equivalent to $h'(c)=0$ which is the result of the Roll's theorem.

Thus the $$h(x)=f(x)[g(b)-g(a)]-g(x)[f(b)-f(a)]$$ defined as in the solution serves its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the given equation as $f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]-g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)]=0$ you can easily recognize this equation as saying that the derivative of $f(x)[g(b)-g(a)]-g(x)[f(b)-f(a)]$ is $0$.

Comment: I understand the proceeding steps of the proof given the equation h(x) = f (x)[g(a) − g(b)] − g(x)[f (a) − f (b)] but how do you come up with the equation?

Comment: It is trivial to guess that $Af'(c)+Bg'(c)$ is the derivative of $Af(x)+Bg(x)$ at the point $x=c$, if $A$ and $B$ are constants. That is how how guess what $h$ should be. @Tony

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that both of these answers give $h(x)=f(x)[**g(b)-g(a)**]-g(x)[**f(b)-f(a)**]$ And not the specified $g(a)-g(b)$ and $f(a)-f(b)$. Is there a way to get this with the correct given equation used?